# Android set procentual size to imageView

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-linearlayout

I would like to ask how to set procentual width and height of the imageview?

I tried to find any working solution but none form them ws not working for me.

Thanks for any help.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layoutContainer" android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">
        <!--HERE I NEED TO SET PROCENTUAL HEIGHT -->
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFlag1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/car_finder_logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why do you have relative layout inside linear one?

Comment: You have layout_width defined two times in you `ImageView`. That will not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_weight` will cause the view to consume the height/width of the parent if it is the only child of the parent. Add a `dummy view` to the the `LinearLayout` and set its `android:layout_weight` according to the percentage you needed.

Suppose you need the ImageView to take 50% of the parent, modify the layout as below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutContainer" android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivFlag1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fil_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/car_finder_logo" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set a `LinearLayout` in which, by default the sum of the weights of the children is 1. 
Your `LinearLayout`, which is the rootView, will have one `ImageView` child. To set its height to a percentage, just use a layout_height of 0dp and a layout_weight of 0.3 for 30% or 0.5 for 50%, for example.  Like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<!-- HERE I NEED TO SET PROCENTUAL HEIGHT -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFlag1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

The result is your `ImageView` having 25% of your Layout height:
[image: The result]